# Will I get Halo 5 when it comes out if I get The Master Chief Collection?

Tags: xbox-one, halo-series

I recently bought Halo Master Chief Collection and I was wondering will I "unlock" Halo 5 once it comes out because that's kind of the main reason I bought it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Halo: Master Chief Collection does not come with Halo 5. It did, however, come with access the [Halo 5: Guardians Multiplayer Beta](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Halo_5:_Guardians_Multiplayer_Beta), which ran from December 29 to January 18.

Comment: Note that if you played Halo: Master Chief Collection online in November or December of 2014 you are eligible for Halo 3:ODST for free.